# Enabling unused swap and mkswap UUID option

Tags: swap

I have a swap partition in `/dev/sda3` 
However it seems that it is never being used, even when I am using firefox with 10 open tabs, one of which streaming a video, and with Gimp running:

```
me@ubuntu:~ $ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       5982972    5161852     821120      81616    1008884    1835340
-/+ buffers/cache:    2317628    3665344
Swap:      6163452          0    6163452
```

[help.ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) advises to enable an unused swap partition with the following commands:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo /sbin/mkswap /dev/sda3
sudo swapon -a
```

However my `/etc/fstab` file uses `UUID=` to name devices:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=964a15d7-f696-4d0d-b269-f36d29be93c2 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Since `man mkswap` says that `mkswap` generates a `UUID` if used without the `-U` option, I wonder if am I required to use the `UUID` associated to `/dev/sda3` in `/etc/fstab` when I use `mkswap`:

```
sudo /sbin/mkswap -U 964a15d7-f696-4d0d-b269-f36d29be93c2 /dev/sda3
```

or it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is normal and it only means you don't have to swap.

Swap space is slower than memory. Since you have free memory, the swap space does not need to be used. It's there and available when you use more memory then you have. 6 GB is plenty for your applications.

In fact some of the memory is used for buffering and caching. Linux is keeping a copy of files it has loaded from disk in memory if it has memory available. That is why you should shutdown PC's with a command so that it can flush changes to the file back to disk.

Having enough swapspace means that when applications need more than what you have they can page out memory to disk. Without this you will have out-of-memory issues and applications will crash.

Comment: You are right. I opened another browser with other 10 tabs and another streaming video, and the system started to swap when it was left with 254848 kb of free memory. Being swappines set to 60 I though it would swap earlier.